# @2x retina image not displaying on retina device (iPod touch) or simulator (iPhone 4)

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

This is my first foray into designing two versions of images for retina or non-retina devices, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong, but I created two versions of an image, one is 302x193, the other is 604x386. They are named "displayCell1.png" and "displayCell1@2x.png", respectively.

I also watermarked the @2x image to ensure that I can know if that's the one being displayed. As I understand it, my retina device (or the iPhone 4 simulator) should automagically detect the presence of the @2x version and display that. However, the following code is resulting in only the standard resolution version being displayed. Any help would be appreciated:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static UIImage *bgImage = nil;
    if (bgImage == nil) {
        bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"displayCell1.png"] retain];
    }
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage] autorelease];
    cell.backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft;
}
```

I also tried it with just `imageNamed:@"displayCell1"`, also to no avail.

I can include more detail as needed. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've now watermarked both images to be sure I know what I'm looking at. Cleaning targets didn't help and the images *are* being included in the .app bundle.

Here's image one: [image]

Dimensions are 302x193

Here's image two: [image]

Dimensions are 604x386

And here's what I get when I run w/ the code above (note that cell height is dialed up, so only one cell is showing on-screen):

[image]

I'm pretty stumped here.

Comment: Try cleaning your targets, sometimes that will get it to work (assuming your new images have been added to the project correctly).

Comment: I know you have an iPod touch as the device...but is it just me or is that the wrong simulator? My iPhone (Retina) Simulator doesn't have the speaker and camera at the top and the bottom part is way smaller.

Comment: *shrugs* It's the built-in iPhone 4.3 simulator...

Comment: @KevinLow: Actually, good eye! It would seem I've been using the non-retina simulator for ages without even realizing it (since the mask looks like the face of the iPhone 4 I had no reason to suspect otherwise). After changing the settings in the simulator it seems to be working now. Wish I knew what had fixed the device too (also working now). But the good news is everything seems to be in order.

Comment: try deleting mac os user cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going in to play with the Simulator settings on a whim, I discovered that Hardware > Device was set to `iPhone`, rather than `iPhone (retina)`

[image]

This fixed the problem for the simulator. Unfortunately, although it's now **also** working on the device, I don't completely know what fixed the problem for the device, since any one of the tweaks I've been trying could have been the key, but I was just attempting them on the simulator before going back to the device.

So, for anyone who browses this in the future, I'd say to try everything that was suggested. All seemed like solid recommendations.

Comment: I would say cleaning the target included the new @2x file into the package that wasn't properly included by XCode but you just didn't see it fixed because you were testing it in the non-retina simulator :)

Answer (score 3):

Open the compiled `.app` package in the Finder (right-click it and select Show Package Contents) and make sure that both versions of the image are there. You may have to clean the build folder and recompile if Xcode just forgot to copy the file.

Comment: I confirmed that both versions are there in the `.app` package. Cleaning and recompiling doesn't help, unfortunately. Any other ideas? (I've added some more detail up top, fwiw)

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine to me.

Check that the @2x image is actually included in the package.

Comment: Checked that both are in the package. They are. Any other ideas? (I've added some more detail up top, fwiw)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on xCode 5, and doing a clean and removing the derived data under organizer did it for me.